# Не показывается email после входа

Tags: php

Ребята есть регистрация. После регистрации вы заходите на главную страницу. Рядом есть кнопка настройки. В ней я хочу вывести

Вход:

```html
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
   array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
   array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
   $password = md5($password);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
     header('location: index.php');
   }else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
   }
  }
}
```

Настройки

```html
<?php 
  session_start(); 

  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Вы должны зарегистрироваться";
    header('location: login.php');
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h2>Настройки</h2>
    <a href="settings.php">Настройки</a></span>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <!-- notification message -->
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
      <div class="error success" >
        <h3>
          <?php 
            echo $_SESSION['success']; 
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
          ?>
        </h3>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

  
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
        <p>Имя пользователя <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
        <p>Email <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></strong></p>
        <p>Текущий пароль <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['password']; ?></strong></p>
        <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Регистрация

```
// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'practice');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Требуется имя пользователя"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Требуется email"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "Пароли не совпадают");
    }

    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$email' LIMIT 1";

    if ($user) {
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "Уже есть такой пользователь");
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
            array_push($errors, "Email уже есть");
        }
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";

        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Вы зарегестрированы!";
        header('location: index.php');
    }
}
```

все данные человека, но кроме username ничего не выводит. Что делать?

Comment: Установите Xdebug. Запустите решим отладки. Посмотрите что не так. Если не хотите использовать xdebug, воспользуйтесь `var_dump()` на каждом этапе. Так и найдёте ошибку.

Comment: Пароль хранится в открытом виде? Вот это поворот.

Comment: Откуда взяться значению $email в скрипте входа?